# My program needs to count the number of occurences of letters in a word, but it seems to count only the occurence of letter 'a'

Tags: java, string

I need to accept a String and check how many letters of the alphabet appeared on it. However, it seems to only count how many times 'a' appears and concatenate that count to all the letters. I can't find where the error is. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance! Here's my code and output.

```
package javaPackage;
public class Counter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String letter="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String word="banana";
        char letterArray[]=letter.toCharArray();
        int length = word.length(); 
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<26;i++) {
        while (index < length) {    
            if (word.charAt(index) == letterArray[i]) {
                count++;        
            }           
            index++;
        }   
        System.out.println("Letter " + letterArray[i]+ " appeared "
                + count+ " times");
    }           
   }    
 }
```

Output:

```
Letter a appeared 3 times
Letter b appeared 3 times
Letter c appeared 3 times
Letter d appeared 3 times
Letter e appeared 3 times
Letter f appeared 3 times
Letter g appeared 3 times
Letter h appeared 3 times
Letter i appeared 3 times
Letter j appeared 3 times
Letter k appeared 3 times
Letter l appeared 3 times
Letter m appeared 3 times
Letter n appeared 3 times
Letter o appeared 3 times
Letter p appeared 3 times
Letter q appeared 3 times
Letter r appeared 3 times
Letter s appeared 3 times
Letter t appeared 3 times
Letter u appeared 3 times
Letter v appeared 3 times
Letter w appeared 3 times
Letter x appeared 3 times
Letter y appeared 3 times
Letter z appeared 3 times
```

Comment: After while-loop, you must reset your variable index.

Comment: If you make `count` an array too, then (i) this problem will go away and (ii) you'll be able to get the results in one traversal of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to I reset index and count? I tried to set their values to 0 after the loop  but I get wrong count.

Answer (score 4):

You never reset your `counter` and `index` variables :

```
for (int i=0;i<26;i++) {
  index = 0; // added
  counter = 0; // added 
  while (index < length)  {   
      if (word.charAt(index) == letterArray[i]) {   
          count++;        
      }           
      index++;
  }   
}
```

That said, this implementation is very inefficient. You can count all occurrences in a single for loop.

`countArray[0]` will count the occurrences of 'a', `countArray[1]` will count the 'b's, and so on.

```
String word="banana";
int countArray[]=new int[26];

for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { 
    countArray[word.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
}  
for (int i = 0; i < countArray; i++) { 
    System.out.println("Letter " + (char)('a' + i) + " appeared " + countArray[i] + " times");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting `index` and `count`.So it is showing results obtained for `a` only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset index to 0 once you left the inner loop. Same with count. Otherwise he only runs the inner loop once for the letter A and then never again, because the condition in the while isn't fulfilled.

Edit: efficient solution

```
int[] letterOccurences = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < letterOccurences.length; i++) {
     letterOccurences[i] = 0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
     letterOccurences[letter.charAt(i) % 97]++; 
     // 'a' % 97 will return 0, 'b' % 97 will return 1 and so on. 
     //Thus, in 0 the count of 'a's, in 1 the count of 'b's and so on will be tracked.
}
```